# Common one but got me stumped Sequence contains more than one element, not using SingleOrDefault

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Been trying to sort this and most seem to point to using `SingleOrDefault`, which I'm not but still get the following error:

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005)
: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
at DOAwayFromDesk.GetNextRecord(Int32 user)
```

This is the code

```
public AwayFromDesk GetNextRecord(int user) {
   using (Intranet2012DataContext db = DataHelper.GetDataContext()) {
        if (!db.AwayFromDesks.Any(w => w.ownerlinkid == user && w.enddate >= DateTime.Now && w.complete == false))
            return null;

        return (from a in db.AwayFromDesks
                where a.ownerlinkid == user
                      && a.enddate >= DateTime.Now && a.complete == false
                orderby a.startdate , a.enddate
                select a).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Not sure what else to check for.

Have checked what SQL is getting ran and it's only returning a single record every time.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
(CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [dbo].[AwayFromDesk] AS [t0]
        WHERE ([t0].[ownerlinkid] = @p0) AND ([t0].[enddate] >= @p1) AND (NOT ([t0].[complete] = 1))
        ) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
 END) AS [value]',N'@p0 int,@p1 datetime',@p0=1,@p1='2014-01-24 08:30:28:877'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[id], [t0].[added], [t0].[ownerlinkid], [t0].[startdate], [t0].[enddate], [t0].[reason], [t0].[contact], [t0].[internalmeeting], [t0].[reminder], [t0].[remindertime], [t0].[recur], [t0].[complete]
FROM [dbo].[AwayFromDesk] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[ownerlinkid] = @p0) AND ([t0].[enddate] >= @p1) AND (NOT ([t0].[complete] = 1))
ORDER BY [t0].[startdate], [t0].[enddate]',N'@p0 int,@p1 datetime',@p0=1,@p1='2014-01-24 08:30:28:890'
```

One thing I've noticed and is slightly confusing is the Any is doing this

```
if (!db.AwayFromDesks.Any(w => w.ownerlinkid == user && w.enddate >= DateTime.Now && w.complete == false))
            return null;
```

But the SQL is this

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
(CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [dbo].[AwayFromDesk] AS [t0]
        WHERE ([t0].[ownerlinkid] = @p0) AND ([t0].[internalmeeting] = 1) AND (NOT ([t0].[complete] = 1))
        ) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
 END) AS [value]',N'@p0 int',@p0=1
```

Which has no mention of the enddate I used, but is using internalMeeting, which I'm not using in the Linq statement, weird.

10/Feb/2014::Have now tried changing .Any to .Count, but still get the error randomly.

```
if (db.vwAwayFromDeskAnyChecks.Count(w => w.ownerlinkid == user && w.enddate >= DateTime.Now)==0) return null;
```

This is even the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [vwAwayFromDeskAnyCheck] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[ownerlinkid] = @p0) AND ([t0].[enddate] >= @p1)
```

Stumped?! No idea how this is possible.

Comment: I suggest you turn on logging so you can see what SQL is being executed.

Comment: Annoying thing is, that's it seems purely random, but will check the logging

Comment: What is? (Please edit it into the question.)

Comment: My above error and have added it to my question

Comment: Interesting. Note that it's `Any` that is failing, not `FirstOrDefault`...

Comment: Really, could you expand on that a little please.  I thought any would only return a number

Comment: Well look at the stack trace... `Any` returns `bool` in .NET, via returning a number in the SQL. Yes, I'm surprised it's causing a problem too. You can verify that by adding extra logging before each LINQ call - I suspecty you'll see "About to call Any..." (or whatever you log) but not "About to call FirstOrDefault...".

Comment: Thanks for that, not sure how to correct this will have to do some digging

Comment: The thing about `endDate` and `internalMeeting` makes me suspect an incorrect mapping in the entity definition. If that is the case, then whether it would explain the rest of the issue is another matter.

Comment: Right, have deleted the entity, added it again and also created a smaller sql view and mapped that and used that for the .Any part, just to try and eliminate the problem, will update when I know more, as it's a random event

Comment: Tried changing the Any to Count but still get the error randomly
    if (db.vwAwayFromDeskAnyChecks.Count(w => w.ownerlinkid == user && w.enddate >= DateTime.Now)==0) return null;